# Ember CLI pod structure migration

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-pods

I just started using Ember for a real application, and already got myself into a bit of a bind.

I set up my environment.js file with the following:

```
modulePrefix: 'appname',
podModulePrefix: 'appname/pods'
```

However, this did not work and Ember CLI continues to generate files in the old/normal structure.  I unfortunately did not even notice until I had a decent amount of work done... cause I was excited just to have an Ember app going!  ;)

So the question I have is two-fold:

1. Why is `podModulePrefix` not working?  I've read up on it, and it seems like it should be fine.  I'm probably missing the point on why it's not working.
2. How can I migrate my existing file structure into the pod structure?  Is it just manually doing so, or is there a tool out there that helps with things?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to answer

1- you should just stop Ember and start again and your code should be

```
 podModulePrefix: 'app/pod', //just an example
```

then start creating a test component like

```
ember g component test-com --pod
```

the result would be this

```
installing component
  create app/pod/components/test-com/component.js
  create app/pod/components/test-com/template.hbs
installing component-test
  create tests/integration/pod/components/test-com/component-test.js
```

2- no way, you must just simply create and copy and paste your code.

> If you would like to use the pods structure as the default for your project, you can set usePods in your .ember-cli config file to true (setting was previously named usePodsByDefault). To generate or destroy a blueprint in the classic type structure while usePods is true, use the --classic flag.

With the usePods set to true.

```
// .ember-cli
{
    "usePods": true
}
```

Comment: I am marking your answer as accepted, if only for the 2nd point `"usePods": true`.
That should be way more prevalent in the documentation IMO ;)

I ended up archiving the old project, starting a new one with a bare structure, ensured my config/environment files were correct, and just starting fresh.  Took no time at all to just set up the few routes and components I had.

Thx!